# iOS13 make a background processor to update location

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I know I am not the only person having this issue,

Basiclly it seems like SwiftUI can't request Location Always even if it is inside the info.plist you instead have to add a call to it later on (which I have done.)

The issue I can see happening is that people won't change it from while app in use to always.

So how could one make a background processor to keep updating it? - I see Apple allows a background task to be ran that's all

my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Delivering location based Fuel Price Updates, Weather, News &amp; Sports. As well as local offers.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Delivering location based Fuel Price Updates, Weather, News &amp; Sports. As well as local offers.</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

LocationServices.swift

```
//
//  LocationManager.swift
//  CoreLocationDemo
//
//  Created by Sheikh Bayazid on 7/18/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Sheikh Bayazid. All rights reserved.
//
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine
import UIKit
import SwiftUI


class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private let manager: CLLocationManager
    static var LMlat = 0.0
    static var LMlong = 0.0
    @Published var lastKnownLocation: CLLocation?

    
//    var getLat: String {
//        return "\(lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude)"
//    }
//    var getLon: String {
//        return "\(lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude)"
//    }
    
    
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .denied{
            print("denied")
        }
        else{
            print("athorized")
            manager.requestLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func start() {
        //manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    init(manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()) {
        self.manager = manager
        super.init()
    }
    

    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    
    func startUpdating() {
        self.manager.delegate = self
       // self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        lastKnownLocation = locations.last
       // print(lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude)
        self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if(lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude != LocationManager.LMlat && lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.longitude != LocationManager.LMlong)
        {
            print("Last Known Location Is not a match")
            LocationManager.LMlat = lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude
            LocationManager.LMlong = lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.longitude
            
            updateServerLocation(latitude: LocationManager.LMlat, longitude:  LocationManager.LMlong)
        }
        
        /* Maybe Use in Future Version
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.longitude)
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
            {
                placemarks, error -> Void in

                // Place details
                guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

                // Location name
                if let locationName = placeMark.location {
                    print(locationName)
                }
                // Street address
                if let street = placeMark.thoroughfare {
                    print(street)
                }
                // City
                if let city = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea {
                    print(city)
                }
                // Zip code
                if let zip = placeMark.isoCountryCode {
                    print(zip)
                }
                // Country
                if let country = placeMark.country {
                    print(country)
                }
                
        })
        */
        
        
        //showLocation()
    }
    
    func updateServerLocation(latitude:Double,longitude:Double)
    {
        let locationurl = URL(string: "https://EXAMPLE.com/lat=\(latitude)&long=\(longitude)")!
        //print(locationurl )
        // print("location: \(MusicPlayer.uuid ?? "") lat: \(latitude), long: \(longitude)")
         
          URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: locationurl) { (data, res, err) in
          DispatchQueue.main.async{
           // print("The Server should of updated")
            
              //  guard let data = data else { return }
                
            }
             return
        }.resume()
    }
    

//    func showLocation(){
//        print("From showLocation method")
//        print("Latitude: \(getLat)")
//        print("Longitude: \(getLon)")
//    }
    
    
}
```

and in my ContentView.Swift

```
 var lat: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    var lon: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    init() {
        self.location.startUpdating()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? You don't request always permission anywhere. If you want always, then ask for always, however it doesn't seem like your app really needs always anyway. You also aren't requesting background updates with your when in use permission. I would also suggest that you not init An object like a location manager in your view init, it should be created by your app/scene delegate and added to the environment.

Comment: Your app also looks like it could use significant location change and be much more energy efficient

Comment: @Paulw11 we use background location for audio injection. We have built our own audio injection system which gives users the closest fuel prices while listening to live radio. Also check out //print(lastknownLocation... it’s the following line after that. If you have any suggestions on how to make it more Efficient. I would love to see it.

Comment: Ok, but if you want always, ask for always up front, the user will see a prompt for "when in use" and you will have provisional always if they grant it.  After you have made use of location for some time in the background and the user returns to your app then they will be promoted to update your access, but as I said you don't seem to need always. You should check out the "what's new in Core location" session from WWDC 2019 to understand how provisional always authorisation works.

Comment: Based on the description of your use case you can use significant location change in the background with "when in use" permission.  This will give your location updates every 500m or so, which seems fine for your purposes. You can easily start and stop the background location updates when the user starts and stops the audio stream. You don't need the users location when they aren't playing audio from your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 when in use seems to stop when app is in background mode, that’s why we ask for always. Am happy for you to answer the question with an example of what you would do. Be keen to see your take on what we are needing to do.

Comment: You need to specifically [request background updates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates)  Make sure you watch the video I mentioned. It explains how this stuff works in iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things that I suggest you do to improve your use of location.

Firstly, it seems that you may be getting confused by the fact that when you ask for "always" location permission on iOS 13, the user actually gets prompted for "when in use".  On iOS 13.4 you can trigger a prompt for "always" by first requesting (and receiving) "when in use" and then asking for "always". There are cases where this is the right approach, but I don't think your app is one of them.

You should start by watching [What's new in Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/) from WWDC 2019. It explains how provisional-always location permission works.

Looking at your code, it seems that you are trying to re-invent [significant location change monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service). Core Location can do this for you, providing an update only when the user has moved 500m or more; this sounds like it would suit your use case.

Also, based on your use case I can't see that you actually need "always" permission on ios13+; you can use "when in use" for significant location change monitoring with background mode enabled. You can stop background location updates when the user stops the audio stream; there is no good reason for your app to have access to the user's location when they aren't playing audio.

Note that in iOS 12 and earlier you will need to ask for "always" permission, but since you mention SwiftUI, presumably iOS 13 is your minimum supported version.

Finally, with regard to Swift UI, an object like `LocationServices` should be created in your scene delegate and injected into the environment, not created by a view.

Comment: So ok watched the video and I think your 100% right we could use allowBackgroundLocationUpdate=true. But where do I put it?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your use case, you should set that property on your location manager and start locatiinnuodates (or significant location updates) when you start playing audio since that is when you need location.